# Blender particles poking through object

Tags: particles

I'm making a headdress, I have a furball that suits but when I put it in position, some bits poke straight through other parts of the headress. Which I don't want.

I searched for ways to stop this with collisions etc and other questions here, but setting everything else as collision objects makes no difference so I assume that is just for animations?

I also turned it into a mesh hoping I could give it a hair cut on the offending strands poking through, but no sculpting tools seem to do anything to it.

It's just for a static picture.

What options does blender have to achieve the desired effect of either stopping the fur from passing through other objects, or allowing me to cut them off?

Here's a pic for clarity, you can see several bits of hair spiking through.[image]

Comment: *Particle Edit* mode you can cut hair

Comment: @AllenSimpson I don't see that mode... where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to *Particle Edit* mode will give you several tools including *Cut*

[image]

[image]

Editing a particle system means that you must toss all of your edits to make a change to the *Particle System* settings, so be sure you are at the final stage before editing.

Comment: Cheers. Very nice toolset